# "No route registered for '/ZipDeployUI' in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Am following node application [deployment guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) in Azure app service .After creating the web app in azure it asks to redirect to below url

```
https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI
```

But after redirecting it says.

```
"No route registered for '/ZipDeployUI'
```

Any clue to fix this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI does not work for Linux App Services at this time. Consider using FTP or the ZIP deploy API instead.

Uploading the zip file through the cli.It worked fine for me

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <app_name> --src clouddrive/<filename>.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

You have few options. Don't worry about not having the zipDeploy endpoint. You can ssh file, you can upload from a CLI, and a few others options are also there. Please refer to the below documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on a Linux App Services instance. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-zip-file) for the ZipDeployUI endpoint:

> The above endpoint does not work for Linux App Services at this time.
> Consider using FTP or the ZIP deploy API instead.

Switching to a Windows App Services instance fixed the issue for me.

Comment: moving to windows is not the best solution